# CSS colorize nth child of type in different color

Tags: html, css

I want to select the `nth child of type` and use a different color. I don't want to assign ids to these elements because I generate them with a loop from a template engine.

I took some information from here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp

So this is what I got

```css
#service {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}
#serviceItems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
.serviceItem {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.serviceItemHeader:first-of-type {
  color: #80E000;
}
.serviceItemHeader:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #F97A00;
}
.serviceItemHeader:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: #B277DD;
}
.serviceItemHeader:last-of-type {
  color: #e2c100;
}
```

```html
<div id="service" class="section">
  <div id="serviceItems">
    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">Container 1</h4>
      <h4>Container 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">Container 2</h4>
      <h4>Container 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">Container 3</h4>
      <h4>Container 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">Container 4</h4>
      <h4>Container 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to know why are these headers colorized with the same color? I would expect them having different colors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/206/

Comment: Directly from the source you linked: "The `:first-of-type` selector matches every element that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this question has been asked and answered. But specifically to your problem, you need to evaluate `.serviceItem` using `nth-of-child` and then apply the result to the underlying `.serviceItemHeader` class.

```css
#service {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

#serviceItems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.serviceItem {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.serviceItem:first-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #80E000;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(2) .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #F97A00;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(3)  .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #B277DD;
}

.serviceItem:last-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #e2c100;
}
```

```html
<div id="service" class="section">
  <div id="serviceItems">

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 1
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 1
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 2
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 2
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 3
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 3
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 4
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 4
      </h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation is that the `*-of-type` selectors work for sibling elements. The elements you're trying to colorize are in your case "cousins" and so it won't work the way you did it.

To fix it, use the `*-of-type` selector on the parents and once you've selected the parent, just proceed to colorizing the headers.

```css
#service {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

#serviceItems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.serviceItem {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.serviceItem:first-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #80E000;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(2) .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #F97A00;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(3) .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #B277DD;
}

.serviceItem:last-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #e2c100;
}
```

```html
<div id="service" class="section">
  <div id="serviceItems">

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 1
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 1
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 2
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 2
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 3
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 3
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 4
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 4
      </h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS counts elements as children of their direct parent, so each of those headers are counted as the first child below their `.serviceItem` parent. So in this case, you can fix it by doing this:

```css
#service {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}

#serviceItems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.serviceItem {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.serviceItem:first-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #80E000;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(2) .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #F97A00;
}

.serviceItem:nth-of-type(3) .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #B277DD;
}

.serviceItem:last-of-type .serviceItemHeader {
  color: #e2c100;
}
```

```html
<div id="service" class="section">
  <div id="serviceItems">

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 1
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 1
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 2
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 2
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 3
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 3
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="serviceItem">
      <h4 class="serviceItemHeader">
        Container 4
      </h4>
      <h4>
        Container 4
      </h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```